# How to encode ç ö ü in a secure way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, encoding, special-characters

I'm trying to implement a turkish content manager using c# MVC Razor.

I know I can use `@Html.Raw(model.content)` in order to get non-encoded texts, but this can also create some security issues, Xss, injections etc..

Instead if I just use `@model.content` to display text directly, I'm getting the following html source, which I think could create SEO issues as well

```
@model.content outputs : ......g&#252;vece d&#246;k&#252;n.......
```

The original text was

```
@Html.Raw(model.content) outputs : ......güvece dökün.......
```

How to avoid mvc to encode following charcter and keep html secure at the same time ?

> ç, ü , ö

Of course I can create my own html extention, but I'd like to know if there is a secure and reliable method of this?

Comment: Looks like `model.content` has a HTML entities like `&#252;` instead of Unicode characters. Check HTML source of your page, may be you'll see `&amp;#252;`? If so, call `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode` for `model.content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i mentioned on my question ,  i sorted it out using html helper extesion

```
   @{
    string v = "<script>I Ğ Ü İ Ş Ç Ö ö ç i ş ü ğ ı ü ğ p ı o . ö ö ç ı ı n ü ğ ş a l e r t'\'\\'(x)</script>";
        @Html.SafeHtml(v);
        @Html.SafeHtmlV2(v);
    }

//code above outputs: &lt;script&gt;I Ğ Ü İ Ş Ç Ö ö ç i ş ü ğ ı ü ğ p ı o . ö ö ç ı ı n ü ğ ş a l e r t&#39;&#39;\&#39;(x)&lt;/script&gt
```

And my extension classs as follows, you can choose to replace characters one by one (method SafeHtmlV2) or interate usign an array (method SafeHtml),

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString SafeHtml(this HtmlHelper html, string input)
    {
        string[] decodeItems = new string[] { "&#252;", "&#246;", "&#231;", "&#220;", "&#199;", "&#214;" };
        string str = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(input);
        foreach (string s in decodeItems)
        {
            str = str.Replace(s, System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s));
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(str);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SafeHtmlV2(this HtmlHelper html, string input)
    {
        string str = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(input).Replace("&#252;", "ü")
               .Replace("&#246;", "ö")
               .Replace("&#231;", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#231;"))
               .Replace("&#220;", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#220;"))
               .Replace("&#199;", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#199;"))
               .Replace("&#214;", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#214;"));
        return new MvcHtmlString(str);
    }

}
```